# Understanding Irish Baptismal registration of Owen Leahy in 19 Aug 1852

Tags: baptism-records, ireland

Ancestry.com claims that this is a Baptismal record for Owen Leahy, son of Owen Leahy and Peg Walsh. Looking at the source material, I don't understand how they determined the name (or age) of the child.

My attempt to digitize the doc is as follows:

> 19 Aug 1852
> Cath of Owen Leahy (a ??? tinker) and Peg Walsh of Kilmacabea. 4th. Finn and Jude Day.

[image: capture of the source material]

Here's the original source:

- https://registers.nli.ie/registers/vtls000633310#page/19/mode/1up
- https://www.ancestry.com/imageviewer/collections/61039/images/04801_08_0019

Am I misunderstanding the source material? Can anyone help me translate the cursive/irish  better?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, a note on how to read this page. This documents the baptism and "reception into the church" of multiple people, one per line. Only the first date of each month is fully spelled out, and all other dates in the month are just given by the day number of the month.

The excerpt given starts with 7 August 1852. The next line is 8 August 1852, the row after that 10 August 1852, and so on.

The line in question is for 19 August 1852. It appears to read:

> Cath<sup>e</sup> (a bastard) of Owen Leahy (A Kerry tinker) & Peg Walsh of Kilmacabea, J.h. Finn & Jude Daly

If I had to guess, I would guess that Cath<sup>e</sup> is "Catherine," not Owen. If what you see in the original document conflicts with the transcription/indexing, go with the original document.

[Kilmacabea](https://www.townlands.ie/cork/kilmacabea/) is a parish of County Cork.

County Kerry is next to County Cork. There are also several places within County Cork named Kerry-something.

Comment: This is really helpful! For whatever reason I didn't think that Cath would be Catherine, even though that was the child of their's that I knew of.

Comment: Do you have any sense of JH Finn and Jude Daly on the document? The only thing that made sense to me was that they were the Godparents / Sponsors of the baptism.

Comment: Godparents or sponsors would be a reasonable assumption. Possibly if you flip backwards through the book, there may be some column headings on some of the pages.